# MongoDB Aggregation query to select document with min and max dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents that contains 3 fields DateTime, Score, and Name. I would like to limit data to display only relevant information on mongo charts. Basically what I need is to select document with Minimal date and Maximum date and pass this information to MongoDB charts. Can you please suggest the best way, how can I do this?

Example document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62f172b99d3a18179cee4c4c"
  },
  "Name": "pc",
  "Score": 46,
  "DateTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1659646800000"
    }
  }
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62f172b99d3a18179cee4c4c"
  },
  "Name": "pc",
  "Score": 46,
  "DateTime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1649646800000"
    }
  }
}
```

There are number of these kinds of documents and have different values taken at different time period. So I was able to write simple query to Sort by date and limit to one entry which returns only document with minimal date or maxium. Expected output for mew would be to return both of them

Comment: Pls include sample json documents and expected output

Comment: Thank you I have update question, please let me know if I should provide more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB v5.0+, you can use `$setWindowFields` to compute a rank according to ascending and descending sort of `DateTime`. Then pick those with `rank: 1` to choose the max/min `DateTime`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "DateTime": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "minRank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "DateTime": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "maxRank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$minRank",
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$maxRank",
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // cosmetics
    "$unset": [
      "minRank",
      "maxRank"
    ]
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hUVYqCD5Zo2) for your reference.